# Is maintaining a property getter method a good practice even though that property does not exist anymore?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm refactoring a class like this:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class A {

  // more properties

  protected final B b;

}
```

I've been told to remove `b` from this class, for which I should create an interface which will be implemented by extending classes which actually keep this property, so that code is not broken. Thus, I've created an interface:

```
public interface HasB {

  B getB();

}
```

and all child classes of `A` which need property `B` will implement it. For instance:

```
@Getter
public class C extends A implements HasB {

  // more properties

  private final B b;

}
```

So far, so good. The real problem I'm facing now is I got compiling errors whenever `getB` was invoked from any method which receives an `A` type parameter:

```
public void method(A a) {
  a.getB();
}
```

This code now fails to compile since `getB` does not exist anymore. The most immediate solution would be to check if these instances implement `HasB`, then perform casting and finally invoking the method. But this would make me to perform the same kind of check in different parts of the application. I was wondering then if it would be a good solution to create a `getB` method in `A` which does the checking and safely gets `b`. However, I'm not sure this is a good practice, since the goal was removing `b` property from `A`, and moving it into classes where it is really needed

Comment: I think that you should provide a default method for getB() which throws an UnsupportedOperationException. Then have A implement HasB() interface but do not override the method. and in C, you can override the method since property B actually exists

Comment: Also, as Valerij mentioned, your method should take arguments of type HasB

Comment: @experimentunit1998X why would you want to have a `getB` method in `A` when it only throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Comment: @ValerijDobler Well, its based on OP's requirements. Although it used to be possible, it now is an invalid operation due to removal of b. I m basing it off the Java List which throws UnsupportedOperationException for add/removal (immutable list).

Comment: @experimentunit1998X OP tries to be backwards compatible, and throwing in the A makes no sense in this scenario.

Comment: @ValerijDobler I m not familiar with coding things to be backwards compatible, but if the new version already removes B, and the old version still has getB() and tries to call getB() wouldnt it still not be backwards-compatible? Though I know the best would be to have the method accept an argument of the interface instead of A

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a method to accept `A` then the argument is cast down to type `A`, even when you call it with a type `C`. You should change that method to accept `C` instead when you do more with the passed argument but if you only call `getB` on it, then the method only needs to accept `B`.

But are you sure that no class extends A directly anymore?

In the end, you didn't really remove the method. Why not mark the getter as @deprecated and remove it, when no one is using it anymore?

Comment: Sorry, I explained myself badly. Please take a look since I've edited the question.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. The problem is I have several classes extending `A`. Some of them implement `HasB` because they have a `B` property, while the rest does not. So my problem really is how to maintain backwards compatibility in `method`. I want to know what's the best approach for this

Comment: What is the compatibility here? Do you want to extend from A, B and C?

Comment: `C` and other classes extend from `A`. `C` and some other extensions (not all of them) have a `B` property

Comment: Look at my answer. It depends on what your method is doing in particular. Accepting A will always fail, that is why it is not compiling. It needs to accept at least B, but if it only makes sense with C then it has to accept C.